# basic theoretical question regarding difference between a formula and a proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

i am trying to understand the difference between a formula and a proposition, so i have a basic theoretical question regarding the difference between a formula and a proposition:

let's look at if $\not \vDash \omega$ then $\vDash \lnot \omega$:

what would be the difference if $\omega$ was a formula or a proposition?

trying to understand the difference between $\omega$ being a formula or a proposition. if you can, please explain the difference so i can learn and understand.

thank you very much for your help

EDIT: the question is about propositional logic, not how we interpret formulas. i am trying to understand if in one case the statement might not hold true and in the other it will(if $\omega$ is a formula or if it is a proposition).

i am wondering if in any case, $⊭ω$ then $⊨¬ω$ might be wrong(not correct) for one(either proposition or formula), but if we say that $\omega$ is the other, then it would be correct. trying to understand the difference

EDIT2: the connection between a formula and a proposition according to my textbook: a formula will be called a proposition iff it doesn't have any free variable. that is, if all of the occurrences of the variables in the formula are bound variables.

Comment: What is your text (including any sort of handout) and how has it used those terms?

Comment: it's not from a handout or homework. i am trying to understand the difference between a formula and a proposition. i took a simple "if ... then" and wanted to see how it changes if $\omega$ was a formula or a proposition$

Comment: The difference is usually informal.  Usually a formula is something that allows you to "form" a value.  A formula is usually something like $x = \text{Some calculations}$.  For example, both $\ln(e) = 1$ and $e = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 1/k!$ are propositions involving $e$, but only the second would be called a formula.

Comment: @DanielV I would call your first example a formula and a proposition, but I would only call the second a proposition.  An infinite sum is not something that can get written down, and thus it can't have a form.  I think of a formula as necessarily having a form.  Since the second can't have a form, it's not a formula... to me.  Don't both equations allow you to form a truth value?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood No one says "I need a formula for $\top$".  And if someone said "I need a formula for $e$", they'd probably want something like the second.  The first would usually just be called an identity.

Comment: For example see "formulas for PI" : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html

Comment: The meaning of the term "formula" depends on the context, I'm afraid. DanielV is right about a common use of the term formula, but that is not how the term is usually used in mathematical  logic. Even within mathematical logic there is no general agreement about what proposition means.

Comment: it is about propositional logic, not how we interpret formulas. i am trying to understand if in one case the statement might not hold true and in the other it will(if $\omega$ is a formula or if it is a proposition)

Comment: Propositional logic as defined where? Unfortunately, the use of these terms varies from text to text. We can't help you understand what you are are reading unless you tell us what you are reading!

Comment: With "proposition" do you mean a *propositional letter*, like $p_i$ ? If so, it is also an *atomic* formula, i.e. a formula without occurrences of *connectives*. We have to noto that in propo calculus $\vDash \omega$ mean aslo that $\omega$ is a *tautology* : a single propo letter cannot be a tautology.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA this is what i was referring to. could you elaborate please? plus i'm editing the post to explain what the connection between a proposition and a formula according to my textbook

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, does the relation between bound or free variable may change the outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding *propositional calculus*, for every $p$ atomic we may have a truth valuation $v$ such that $v(p)=$ TRUE and a different truth valuation $v′$ such that $v′(p)=$ FALSE.

Thus, neither $\vDash p$ nor $\vDash ¬p$, because the example shows that both are not tautologies : a formula is a *tautology* if it is evaluated to TRUE by **every** truth assignment.

In propositional calculus we have tautologies : $p \lor \lnot p$, contradicitions : $p \land \lnot p$, and satisfiable formulas : $p \land q$.

> It is not true, in general, that the negation of a formula that is **not** a *tautology* must be a tautology.

See $p \land q$ above; it is not a tautology : consider the truth assignment $v$ such that $v(p)=$ FALSE.

But also its negation : $\lnot (p \land q)$ is not Consider the truth assignment $v$ such that $v(p)=v(q)=$ TRUE.

In symbols :

> > $\nvDash p \land q \text { and } \nvDash \lnot (p \land q)$.

---

For *predicate logic*, we have to take into account *free* variables, and the situation is similar.

A formula with free occurrences of variables, like e.g $(x=0)$, is satisfiable. Consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers.

But also its negation : $\lnot (x=0)$ is satisfiable in the same domain.

For predicate logic, we have that $\vDash \varphi$ means that the formula $\varphi$ is *valid*, i.e. TRUE in every interpretation.

But if we consider the relation between the formula and a specific interpretation, we have that :

> if $\varphi$ is a *sentence*, i.e. a formula with **no** occurrences of free variable, and $\mathcal M$ is an interpretation with domain $M$, then :
>
> > $\mathcal M \vDash \lnot \varphi \text { iff } \mathcal M \nvDash \varphi$.

Consider the *sentence* $\forall x (x=0)$ with the usual interpretation with domain $\mathbb N$.

We have that :

> > $\mathbb N \nvDash \forall x (x=0) \text { and } \mathbb N \vDash \lnot \forall x (x=0)$.

Note that the last one is equivalent to : $\exists x \lnot (x=0)$.

Comment: thank you very much. studying your answer